# REST API on CKan resource/datastore

Tags: api, rest, ckan

The title can be confusing, but suppose you have inserted data into datastore using CKan API:

```
curl -X POST http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/datastore_create -H "Authorization: " -d @mycompanydata.json
```

With help of action API I could fetch data as follows:

http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=&filters={“hid”:”23455-XJ31”}

But my requirement is to access the resource data using a RESTful API for example:

```
/hidservice/{resource-id}/{hid}.json
```

1. Can I do this in CKan by default or using an CKan extension plugin? If yes which one?
2. Do I need to need to write my own application to expose RESTful services on the data? If yes, is there a point in using CKan then?
3. Or simply CKan is just not suitable for this if my requirement is to expose RESTful services in different formats like XML, JSON on a available data.       `/hidservice/{resource-id}/{hid}.xml` `/hidservice/{resource-id}/{hid}.json`

Comment: Made some changes to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

CKAN Datastore is a thin wrapper around Postgres to provide APIs to upload tabular data and two sorts of queries, neither of which are RESTful. It's only a few screenfuls of code, which you could skim and understand in 15 minutes.

Maybe you could take what you need from it and write the rest. However that would be only really thinking of yourself.

I'd be much more heartened if you embraced the CKAN community and presented the argument for how Datastore really should provide RESTful interface and worked with them to provide it for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use Postman for a start
or

directly into Chrome ex.

https://api.energidataservice.dk/datastore_search_sql?sql=select * from "02356e88-7c4e-4ee9-b896-275d217cc1b9" where "HourUTC" > ((now() at time zone 'UTC') - interval '7 days') order by "HourUTC" desc